# Symfony PUT method

Tags: php, symfony, put

I want send data via PUT method, my controller action:

```
public function updateTestAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $progress = $em->getRepository('CodeCatsPanelBundle:Progress')->find(5);
    //$form = $this->createForm(new ProgressType(), $progress, array('method' => 'PUT'))->add('submit', 'submit');
    $form = $this->createForm(new ProgressType(), $progress)->add('submit', 'submit');

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render('CodeCatsPanelBundle:Progress:test.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'valid' => $form->isValid(),
        'progress' => $progress,
        'request' => $request
    ]);
}
```

the first one form works correct, but when I change method to PUT I receive validation error:

> This form should not contain extra fields.

I know that Symfony2 use post and extra hidden field _method but how to valid data in this case?

Answer (score 2):

just add a hidden input in your template like:

```
<form action='your route'>
  <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='PUT'>
  //do something.......
</form>
```

in your action:

```
public function updateTestAction(Request $request)
{
   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $progress = $em->getRepository('CodeCatsPanelBundle:Progress')->find(5);
   $form = $this->createForm(new ProgressType(), $progress)->add('submit', 'submit');

   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isValid()){
     //do something
   }

   return $this->render('CodeCatsPanelBundle:Progress:test.html.twig', [
       'form' => $form->createView(),
       'valid' => $form->isValid(),//you need this? 
       'progress' => $progress,
       'request' => $request
   ]);
}
```

in your route config file:

```
 yourRouteName:
    path:      /path
    defaults:  { _controller: yourBundle:XX:updateTest }
    requirements: 
      _method: [PUT]
```

Comment: I think you also need to set `http_method_override` in your framework config. The details are on http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override

Answer (score 1):

> Most browsers do not support sending PUT and DELETE requests via the
> method attribute in an HTML form.
>
> Fortunately, Symfony provides you with a simple way of working around
> this limitation.

## Symfony 3

1. Enable [http-method-override](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override)

In `web/app.php`:

```
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride(); // add this line
```

2. Choose one of the following override:

<kbd>In a Twig Template</kbd>

```
{# app/Resources/views/default/new.html.twig #}
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('target_route'), 'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

<kbd>In a Form</kbd>

```
form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('target_route'),
    'method' => 'GET',
));
```

<kbd>In a Controller / the lazy way</kbd>

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('target_route'))
    ->setMethod('GET')
    ->add('task', 'text')
    ->add('dueDate', 'date')
    ->add('save', 'submit')
    ->getForm();
```

## Post-Symfony 2.2

Same as above, just Step 2, Step 1 is done by default.

## Pre-Symfony 2.2

Same as above, Step 1 and 2.

---

#### References

- [Faking the method with `_method`](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/routing/method_parameters.html#faking-the-method-with-method)
- [Changing the action and methods in a form](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/book/forms.html#book-forms-changing-action-and-method)
- Symfony configuration with [`http-method-override`](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/configuration/framework.html#configuration-framework-http-method-override)